# Перенос данных с MS SQL Server в mySQL (из бекапа)

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли как то портировать базу данных с MS SQL Server 2016 на MySQL (последнюю версию). В базе данных 10 таблиц, 15 stored procedures, 2 триггера, 3 функции и 3 views, они большей частью не большого объёма. Для работы доступен файл БД с расширением .bak

И если возможно, то как это сделать наиболее быстрым путём, учитывая что я работаю с MS SQL Server, но никогда не работал с mySQL.

Спасибо!

Comment: А английском SO уже разбирали этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156279/how-to-import-a-sql-server-bak-file-into-mysql?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Процедуры, функции и триггера 99% придется переписывать. Вьюхи - как повезет. Таблицы и данные должны зайти, если их выгрузить в sql скрипт